# ObservableCollection in XAML definition = Items mixed up

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

My C# Code:

```
namespace App1 {

public sealed partial class MyUserControl1 : UserControl {

    public ObservableCollection<Foo> Foos
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Foo>)GetValue(FoosProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FoosProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FoosProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Foos", typeof(ObservableCollection<Foo>), typeof(MyUserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Foo>()));

    public MyUserControl1() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class Foo : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public ObservableCollection<Bar> Bars
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Bar>)GetValue(BarsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BarsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Bars.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BarsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Bars", typeof(ObservableCollection<Bar>), typeof(Foo), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Bar>()));

    public Foo() {
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class Bar {

    public Bar() {
    }
}
}
```

My XAML Code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <local:MyUserControl1 x:Name="Ctrl1">
            <local:MyUserControl1.Foos>
                <local:Foo>
                    <local:Foo.Bars>
                        <local:Bar/>
                    </local:Foo.Bars>
                </local:Foo>
                <local:Foo>
                    <local:Foo.Bars>
                        <local:Bar/>
                    </local:Foo.Bars>
                </local:Foo>
            </local:MyUserControl1.Foos>
        </local:MyUserControl1>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

In Debugger I get the following Result:

[both Bar objects are in both Foo objects Bars Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNmXB.png)

But I would expect to show one Bar in each Foo Bars Collection.

In the Debugger I actually recognized that if I remove one Bar from one Collection it gets removed from both - so the both collections are a reference to the same object.

Im quite confused

It's my first question in Stackoverflow.
Perhaps it's allready been asked - I can't find the answer - been searching for quiet a long time now...
Although I'm new to uwp and xaml and I can imagine it is not best practice.

[Sample Project](http://www.xup.in/dl,19708749/App1.zip/)

Comment: I stripped down everything to post a sample - actually I want this Collection to hold settings. no UI elements. And would like to get ride of this cross reference between those two collections that got nothing to do with each other. (<local:Foo.Bars> from first Foo and <local:Foo.Bars> from second Foo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your binding you are using Observable collections. Observable collections have the property of updating whenever a change is made. In your XAML first half

```
 <local:Foo>
  <local:Foo.Bars>
  <local:Bar/>
  </local:Foo.Bars>
 </local:Foo>
```

Current Foo count=1 Bars count=1

 you are adding For Myusercontrols.foo and Foo.bar value. Now in second half you are adding more values to the same Observable list Foo and Bar you are adding more values to the same list. So when you repeat that again then
Current Foo count=2 Bars count=2
 
What you need is not to reference the current lists but Create a new Foo and add that to your MyUserControl1

Comment: Changing to a List<Foo> and a List<Bar> solved the issue - I can't figure out why - I thought i would instanciate a new ObservableCollection<Bar> on my 2 Foo objects